# Ruby - Check the length of each words and group them

Tags: ruby

I can't find the methods used to check the length of each word and group them per length.

arr = ["john","roger","matt","john", "james", "Jennifer"]

The method should return:

There are 3 names with 4 characters
There are 2 names with 5 characters
There is 1 names with 1 character

I tried this one and it's working

```
arr.group_by(&:length).transform_values(&:count)
```

Thank you

Comment: Methods are not something you _find_. They are something you _write_. Show us your code and explain what issue it is having.

Comment: You can start off with getting length of each word into a hash
```ruby
arr.each { |word|
  length = word.length
  hash[word.to_sym] = length }
```
or into an array
```ruby
new_arr = arr.map{ |word| {word => word.length}}
```

Comment: _"There is 1 name with 1 character"_ – not really :-)

Comment: `arr.group_by(&:length).transform_values(&:count)` works just fine, so why is this a question? It would be more appropriate to make that part of your question an answer. It's not terribly uncommon for those posting questions to also post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one will do

```ruby
arr.map(&:size).tally
```

but you need Ruby versions >= 2.7

Answer (score 0):

`each_with_object` is your key.

```rb
arr = %w[john roger matt john james Jennifer]
res = 
  arr.each_with_object({}) do |name, obj|
    obj[name.length] ||= []
    obj[name.length].push(name)
  end
```